# Recognize smallest, middle and biggest value

Tags: c

I am learning programming, could you help me and tell me what is wrong?
program should recognize smallest, middle and biggest value and assign it to d1, d2, d3 in this order

```
void three_function(double * pnt_d1, double * pnt_d2, double * pnt_d3){

    double smallest, middle, largest;
    largest = *pnt_d1;
    smallest = *pnt_d2;
    middle = *pnt_d3;

    if (*pnt_d2 > largest)
        largest = *pnt_d2;

    else if (*pnt_d3 > largest)
        largest = *pnt_d3;

    else if (*pnt_d1 < smallest)
        smallest = *pnt_d1;

    else if (*pnt_d3 < smallest)
        smallest = *pnt_d3;

    else if ((*pnt_d1 > smallest) && (*pnt_d1 < largest))
        middle = *pnt_d1;

    else if((*pnt_d2 > smallest) && (*pnt_d2 < largest))
        middle = *pnt_d2;

    *pnt_d1 = smallest;
    *pnt_d2 = middle;
    *pnt_d3 = largest;

}
```

Bad execution:

```
Please enter 3 double values: 1 2 3
```

(on start)
    Now d1 = 1.000000, d2 = 2.000000 and d3 = 3.000000

(after three_function)
    Now d1 = 2.000000, d2 = 3.000000 and d3 = 2.000000

Comment: why you didn't use multiple statements using `&&` in if which will make the code and debugging easy

Comment: I use && to find middle value, after recognition the biggest and the smallest. If there is more efficient way, please describe it, I will be grateful.

Comment: I prefer this way http://ideone.com/RdEI2u , suit yourself in which you are comfortable :) @Misiek777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically if the following `if` succeeds, none of the other statements are executed because they are in `else if`. So you want to remove all `else` and just check `if(condition)` 6 times. So something like

```
if (*pnt_d2 > largest)
    largest = *pnt_d2;

if (*pnt_d3 > largest)
    largest = *pnt_d3;

 ....
```

Comment: Thank you, stupid mistake. Is there any better way to recognize these values?

Comment: To me this is the most readable code for a beginner. It can be made terse but won't be readable - and compilers are smart enough to optimize these things anyways , so when I am learning, I'd focus on readability than it being terse. Let me still think if some if conditions can be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Here the issue:

```
if (*pnt_d2 > largest) // 2 > 1
    largest = *pnt_d2; // largest = 2
else if...
```

Because of `else if` code jumps there:

```
*pnt_d1 = smallest; // not changed and equal to 2
*pnt_d2 = middle;   // not changed and equal to 3
*pnt_d3 = largest;  // updated by 'if' and equal to 2
```

Comment: This assumption is on the end of the function after I recognize the smallest, middle and biggest value, I use it to have this order (smallest - d1, middle - d2, biggest - d3). I still don't understand :(